# Apache config for conditional authorization

Tags: apache

I want to do conditional authorization based on SERVER_URI (test-oidc.com, test-kerberos.com), authorize with `openid-connect` if test-oidc.com or authorize with `kerberos` if test-kerberos.com, how can I specify this (in AuthType may be)?

```
auth-apache-directive-block:
    block-name = Location
    block-arg = "/"
    AuthType = openid-connect  --> how can also specify authorize with kerberos if server_uri is test-kerberos.com
    Require = valid-user
    LogLevel = debug
```